# jQuery - Access Data Attribute in Button Click Event

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have the following button:

```
<button id="btnDeleteCoverage" type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-xs delete-btn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#deleteCoverageModal" data-analystId="@item.AnalystID" data-secSymbol="@item.SecSymbol" data-Status="@item.Status"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></button>
```

As you can see, it has this (and other data attributes):

```
     data-Status="@item.Status"
```

I want to access the value that this is set to in the following click event for the button:

```
 $("#btn_delete_coverage").click(function (e) {
            // get the value for the data attributes here and use in postdata
            var postdata = { "analystID": /* use value here */, "symbol": /* use value here */, "status": /* use value here */ };

     //etc
});
```

EDIT:

I have tried using the jQuery data and attr functions, but can't get it to work.

I tried

```
     var analystID = $(this).attr('data-analystId');
```

and

```
     var analystID = $(this).data('data-analystId');
```

and
    var analystID = $(this).data('data-analystId');

but get "undefined" each time.

Comment: I inserted your html into my developer tools in Chrome and used this:                        $('#btnDeleteCoverage').attr('data-analystid'); and it returned "@item.AnalystID", so I would say using attr works

Comment: _"I have tried using the jQuery data and attr functions, but can't get it to work"_ - I don't see `.data()` or `.attr()` in your example, or an error message.

Comment: Indeed. Please see my EDIT.

Comment: The `.attr()` version should work, the `.data()` ones not (see the documentation for the _why_). _"but get "undefined" each time"_ -> Please add a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve/) which shows the actual problem.

Comment: Thanks for your help, Andreas. It was a mistake on my part, as mentioned below.

Comment: `$(this).data('analystid');` (note lower case). Refer also [specifications](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#custom-data-attribute)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the .attr() method to access custom attributes.
For example:

```
 $("#btn_delete_coverage").click(function (e) {
        // get the value for the data attributes here and use in postdata
        var analystID = $(this).attr('data-analystId');
        var postdata = { "analystID": analystID, "symbol": /* use value here */, "status": /* use value here */ };

 //etc
});
```

EDIT:
Apparently the selector was the problem, it should've been $("#btnDeleteCoverage")

Comment: Tried it but got "undefined". Please see my EDIT.

Comment: I also see it should be $("btnDeleteCoverage") instead of $("#btn_delete_coverage").

Comment: Yeah, I was just coming back here to note that. But thanks for pointing it out. This is the problem.

Comment: The preferred method is `var analystID = $(this).data('analystid');` - but the attributes must all be lower case as per the specifications